# Why can I not get subplot ylabels to show up in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-lab, subplot, cartopy

I cannot figure out why the y-axis labels aren't showing up in the figures.

```
nc=21 #number of subplot columns

import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
data = np.random.rand(nc*2, 15, 29)

title_list = ['elnino', 'neutral',]

proj = ccrs.PlateCarree(central_longitude=180, globe=None)
kwargs_pcol = dict(cmap=plt.cm.RdBu_r, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())
lats = np.linspace(-90, 90, data.shape[1])
longs = np.linspace(-180, 180, data.shape[2])

fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=nc, ncols=2, subplot_kw=dict(projection=proj), figsize=(12, 48), sharex=True, sharey=True)
for i, (ax, data_slice) in enumerate(zip(axs.T.ravel().flat, data)):
    ax.coastlines()
    if i<nc:
        p = ax.pcolormesh(longs, lats, data_slice, shading='auto', vmin=0, vmax=1,) #el,
    else:
        p = ax.pcolormesh(longs, lats, data_slice, shading='auto', vmin=0, vmax=1,) #n,
    cbar = plt.colorbar(p, ax=ax)
    if i%nc==0:
        ax.set_title(f"{title_list[int(i/nc)]}_{i}")
    ax.set_ylabel('Y')
    
plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.02, hspace=0.1)
```